# How to calculate the line integral $\int_{\vec{\gamma_j}}\langle\vec{v_k},d\vec{x}\rangle$ for $j=1,2$ and $k=1,2,3$

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Here's the integral again: $$\int_{\vec{\gamma_j}}\langle\vec{v_k},d\vec{x}\rangle$$

Here's what I know about $\vec{\gamma_1},\vec{\gamma_2}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$

$$\vec{\gamma_1}(t) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
t \\
t+1 \\
t
\end{array}
\!\right) 
\;,\; \vec{\gamma_2}(t) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
t \\
t^2+1 \\
t
\end{array}
\!\right) $$

And the vector fields $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are continuous and differentiable:

$$\vec{v_1}(x,y,z) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
x^2-y \\
y^2+x \\
z
\end{array}
\!\right) 
\;,\;\vec{v_2}(x,y,z) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
x^3-3xy^2 \\
y^3+2yx^2 \\
5
\end{array}
\!\right) 
\;,\;\vec{v_3}(x,y,z) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
f'(x) \\
g'(y) \\
h'(z)
\end{array}
\!\right) $$

I'm new to the concept of calculating line integrals so any advice on how to move forward would be very appreciated.

Comment: $$\int_{\vec{\gamma_j}}\langle\vec{v_k},d\vec{x}\rangle = \int_{a}^b \langle \vec{v_k}(\vec \gamma_j(t)),\vec \gamma'_j(t)\rangle dt$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm not entirely sure how to proceed though. Should I calculate the right hand side integral for each j and k? Appreciate the help!

Comment: I can't see any other way.

Comment: Alright, and then is the combined value of those calculations equal to the left side integral?

Comment: There are $6$ LHS integrals: one for each combination of $j$ and $k$.  Maybe they all evaluate to the same thing -- I don't know, I haven't calculated any of these -- but they are distinct integrals.

Comment: Ok thanks! One question about $v_3$, how am I supposed to interpret for example $f'(x)$? Should I replace it with the derivative of the $x$-value of let's say $\vec{\gamma_1}$

Answer (score 1):

For $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$, there is nothing intelligent to do but compute, compute, compute. While boring, this is a necessary exercise to get a feeling about what line integrals are and how they are computed.

$\vec v_3$, on the other hand, is of a different nature. Let $\vec v_3 = (P, Q, R)$. Notice that

$$\frac {\partial P} {\partial y} = \frac {\partial} {\partial y} f'(x) = 0 = \frac {\partial} {\partial x} g'(y) = \frac {\partial Q} {\partial x}$$

and similarly $\frac {\partial P} {\partial z} = \frac {\partial R} {\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial Q} {\partial z} = \frac {\partial R} {\partial y}$.

This has two implications:

1. $\vec v_3$ is a "conservative vector field", meaning that its line integral along *any* path will depend only on the path's endpoints; since your both paths have the same endpoints $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,2,1)$, computing just one of them will give the result for both;
2. there exist a function $F$ (not unique, but you don't care!) such that $\vec v_3 = (\frac {\partial F} {\partial x}, \frac {\partial F} {\partial y}, \frac {\partial F} {\partial z})$ (*in principle, there is an essential topological condition to be checked, but it is met here so I won't mention it in order not to confuse you*).

Who is $F$ in our case? Well, we have that $\frac {\partial F} {\partial x} = f'(x), \ \frac {\partial F} {\partial y} = g'(y), \ \frac {\partial F} {\partial z} = h'(z)$ so you don't have to do a very complicated reasoning because just looking at these relations carefully suggests $F(x,y,z) = f(x) + g(y) + h(z)$ (check for yourself that those relations are true).

This means that if $\gamma : [0,1] \to \Bbb R^3$ is any smooth curve,

$$\int \limits _\gamma \langle \vec v_3, \vec {\Bbb d x} \rangle = \int \limits _\gamma P(x,y,z) \ \Bbb d x + Q(x,y,z) \ \Bbb d y + R(x,y,z) \ \Bbb d z = \\
\int \limits _\gamma \frac {\partial F} {\partial x} \ \Bbb d x + \frac {\partial F} {\partial y} \ \Bbb d y + \frac {\partial F} {\partial z} \ \Bbb d z = \int \limits _\gamma \Bbb d F = \int \limits _0 ^1 F' \big( \gamma (t) \big) \ \Bbb d \big( \gamma (t) \big) = \int \limits _0 ^1 F' \big( \gamma (t) \big) \gamma ' (t) \ \Bbb d t = \\
\int \limits _0 ^1 (F \circ \gamma)' (t) \ \Bbb d t = F \big( \gamma (1) \big) - F \big( \gamma (0) \big) .$$

In your case, $\gamma (0) = (0,1,0)$ and $\gamma (1) = (1,2,1)$, so the result is

$$\big( f(1) + g(2) + h(1) \big) - \big( f(0) + h(1) + g(0) \big)$$

and this is as good as it gets, since you are not given a concrete form for $f,g,h$. Notice that due to the fact that $\vec v_3$ is conservative, the computation didn't need $\gamma$'s formula, only its endpoints.